# Appending Sequelize model fields in NestJs plugin design

Tags: typescript, plugins, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to develop a plugin design logic using NestJS with it's [Dynamic modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) and [EventEmitter](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events)

Purpose is to extending core logic using multiple plugins which are not aware of each other.
Found an nice [plugin loader](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3307).

Idea seemed to work for me, until I ran into issue on emitting Sequalize model instances from the core module.
Exact problem is that Sequalize have loaded specific plugin-module instance which is not aware of other fields and I can't use them inside of other plugin logic unless I create new instance and reload data from database again.

```
Structure:
- core
   - models
      * Customer (fields: {id, name}) 
- plugins
   - pluginA (dependent on core)
      - models
         * Customer extends core/models/Customer (fields: {address}) 
   - pluginB (dependent on core)
      - models
         * Customer extends core/models/Customer (fields: {age})
```

My vision is to able to merge all 3 customers models on application bootstrapping and then add it to Sequalize.

I have tried to use [Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) but it will only merge class functions not properties.
Leaving example script

```
import { Sequelize, Model, Table, Column, DataType } from 'sequelize-typescript';

/** From Core Module  */
@Table({
  tableName: 'customer',
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
})
class CustomerCore extends Model {
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, primaryKey: true })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.TEXT })
  name: string | null;
}

/** From PluginA  */
@Table({
  tableName: 'customer',
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
})
class CustomerA extends CustomerCore {
  @Column({ type: DataType.TEXT, allowNull: true })
  address?: string;
}

/** From PluginB  */
@Table({
  tableName: 'customer',
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
})
class CustomerB extends CustomerCore {
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: true })
  age?: number;
}

/** 
 * Mixins example which wont work 
 * */
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
          Object.create(null)
      );
    });
  });
}
class Customer extends CustomerCore {}
interface Customer extends CustomerCore, CustomerA, CustomerB {};

applyMixins(Customer, [CustomerCore, CustomerA, CustomerB])

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'test',
});

/** Get error: cannot read property 'length' of undefined */
sequelize.addModels([Customer]);
```

Does someone have idea how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.